# Orthonormal bases for Hilbert spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

In Reed and Simon (Functional Analysis) Theorem II.6 states that, given an orthonormal basis $\{ x_\alpha \}_{\alpha \in A}$ (not necessarily countable)for a Hilbert space $H$, every $y \in H$ can be written as a sum
$$
\sum_{\alpha \in A} (x_{\alpha}, y) x_\alpha 
$$ 
where $(\cdot,\cdot)$ denotes the inner product).

The proof uses a conclusion that I cannot quite follow:

By Bessel's inequality we know that for any finite subset $A' \subset A$, $\sum_{\alpha \in A'} |(x_\alpha ,y )|^2 \le \|y\|^2$. Thus $(x_\alpha,y) \ne 0$ for at most a countable number of $\alpha's$ in $A$.

Why can we deduce the last statement ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, consider the set
$$
\{x_{\alpha} : |(x_{\alpha}, y)| \geq 1/n\}
$$
Show that this set is finite, so the union over all the $n$'s is countable, which is the set you are talking about.